# Communicating/reacting to a specific state change between views for two separate yet semi-associated view models

Tags: swift, mvvm, viewmodel, publish-subscribe, combine

I have a view that consists of two subviews with 1) separate internal states but 2) a high-level state that’s noteworthy to any associated views i.e. each other. That is, a change in one’s high-level state should trigger the other to reconsider/change its own. Imagine – in the interest of keeping it simple/generalisable - a header that has a set of buttons that change based on the option selected in the footer. On the flip side, there’s a button in the header that exits the active state and reset it back to its original state (and therefore the footer’s too).

I’ve managed to conveniently achieve this by adopting a shared universal instance for each view’s view model. The header for example was observing changes in the footer’s view model, and therefore is able react to a change in the footer’s high-level state. However, considering the footer had other internal states (i.e. irrelevant to the header but necessary for the footer view that was observing changes to its own view model), the header view was being re-rendered every time there was any change, regardless of relevance, to the footer view. In reality, at least to my eyes, I wouldn’t notice any visual hiccups but I’m aware this is a fundamentally inefficient (and wrong) way to manage the flow of states. And that if this misbehavior was widespread, then performance is likely to become compromised (visible).

What I have is something along the lines of:

```
struct HeaderView: View {
        
    // MARK: Observers
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HeaderViewModel = HeaderViewModel.shared
    @ObservedObject var footerViewModel: FooterViewModel = FooterViewModel.shared
    
    // MARK: -
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch footerViewModel.state {
                case 1: HeaderState1View()
                case 2: HeaderState2View()
                case 3: HeaderState3View()
            }
            Button("EXIT", action: {viewModel.reset()})
        }
    }
}

struct FooterView: View {
        
    // MARK: Observers
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FooterViewModel = FooterViewModel.shared
    
    // MARK: -
    var body: some View {
        Button("State 1", action: {viewModel.state(to: 1)})
            .background(viewModel.state == 1 ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        Button("State 2", action: {viewModel.reset()})
            .background(viewModel.state == 2 ? Color.red : Color.clear)
        Button("State 3", action: {viewModel.reset()})
            .background(viewModel.state == 3 ? Color.red : Color.clear)
    }
}

class HeaderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // ...
    
    func reset() {
        FooterViewModel.shared.reset()
        // and other internal state changes
    }

    // ...
}

class FooterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var state: Int = 1
    // ...
    
    func state(to state: Int) {
        self.state = state
    }

    func reset() {
        self.state = 1
    }

    // ...
}
```

The view models for each is created inside a root-level ViewModel responsible for creating both (and others).

```
class ViewModel {
    var footer = FooterViewModel()
    var header = HeaderViewModel()
    // etc.
}
```

That’s created in @main root struct:

```
@main
struct myApp: App {
    
    // MARK: Variables
    var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    // MARK: Layout
    var body: some Scene {        
        return WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // MARK: -
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            header
            /// other views
            footer
        }
    }
```

Without depending on shared instances of both header and footers’ view models, as I have above, what would the most appropriate/efficient way to achieve what I’m after?

To be more specific/clear, if, for example, the Header and Footer views create a @StateObject of their respective view models i.e.

```
@StateObject var viewModel: FooterViewModel = FooterViewModel() /// in FooterView.swift
@StateObject var viewModel: HeaderViewModel = HeaderViewModel() /// in HeaderView.swift
```

How would I be able let any change in HeaderView communicate back to the instance of FooterViewModel that FooterView created?

EDIT:

I imagine one way to possibly achieve this is if I create a third view model that consists of the published shared state and that it’s passed into both views when they’re initialised. But imagine there was more than one published property that needed to be shared between the views, and that there was another view in the mix that needed access to only one of them – would I create two shared view models then: one with publishers for shared properties between all 3 and another with ones for the 2? Doesn’t seem a practical strategy.

Comment: I may have not fully understood the question (simplifying the question to a minimal and concrete example would help), but if you have a shared state that impacts both header and footer, factor out that state into a shared view model, and "lift" up to their shared ancestor to own.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If I understood correctly, that’s actually along the lines of what I wrote in my edit (suggesting you have understood the question): "I imagine one way to possibly achieve this is if I create a third view model that consists of the published shared state and that it’s passed into both views when they’re initialised. " But as I added, what about a scenario when there’s a third (fourth etc) view that needs access to some of the shared state but *not all*? Does there then need to be 2 view models that the ancestor owns? It doesn’t seem a flexible approach.

Comment: What's your concern with having a superset of all shared states factored out into a single view model? Alternatively, you could use have a shared instance that publishes property changes (e.g. via `@Published` or some other mechanism) and have respective view models subscribe only to changes that they care about (kinda like a notification center)

Comment: My concern, whether valid or not, is for a view model to publish changes to a view concerning properties that it actually doesn’t care about. But, I didn’t realise there is a way for a view to subscribe not to all publishers for an object it observes, but a specific publisher (or more). Is it possible for you to elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: I didn't mean for a view (though you could use `.onReceive`), but the view's view model could subscribe and signal that it's changed, e.g.: `sharedInstance.$prop1.sink { self.objectWillChange.send() }`

Comment: Okay, just to be clear and I avoid any misunderstandings, in your example, would the view model *only* broadcast to its associated view that it needs to be re-rendered when $prop1 in the shared view model has changed? I’m unclear on how, if the view has the shared view model as an @ObservableObject, it can prevent changes to any other properties, besides $prop1. to trigger a re-render? Unless the idea is for it to *not* be observing the shared view model? I think I got it, just writing this out, but your confirmation would be appreciated :) Thanks so much for the support!

Comment: Yes, I meant that the shared instance wouldn't be used as `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` inside views, but only as a singleton that view models subscribe to its notifications